# Problema visualizando JSON en el browser

Tags: express

Paso a comentarles algo que no estoy entendiendo. Estoy practicando Express, al visualizar mis rutas en el localhost, puedo ver los JSON primeramente bien, tengo la extensión JSONview instalada en el browser. Así que en primera instancia se ve bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cuando por ejemplo, en la ruta paso a consultar un lenguaje.

Mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al mirar mi browser, ahora el JSON se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué puede estar pasando aquí? Por qué el cambio de visualización?

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Esto no es ningún problema de programación, ves formateado él .json por la extensión/plugin instalado en tu navegador, lo importante es que el json se encuentre correctamente estructurado.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 cosas:

1. Firefox soporta `JSON` sin ningun complemento
2. En la line `71`

   `res.send(JSON.stringify(result))` estas convirtiendolo en `texto` asi que no hay ningun `"error"` por decirlo, lo conviertes en `texto` y es lo que recives

debes dejarlo solo como `res.send(result)`